# VBS - Create object and pass that through functions and subs?

Tags: arrays, object, vbscript, return

I'm trying something out. I've got this system where a bunch of scripts are triggered at certain event handlers. This is used during the creation of Users in Active Directory.

So, what I think I need is a function that basically collects the properties of the user being processed into - hopefully, an object. And then returning that object and using it in other functions and subs. So that I can perhaps reach the properties I want using only "myObject.firstname" and that's it.

How can I create an object, create and set values in it and returning the entire object? Is this possible in VBS?

Edit: What would be best if I could create an Object that holds these properties and just being able to access them whenever I need to.

I'm basically after something like this:

```
Public Sub Main()
   Set userStream = New objUser
   msgbox objUser.firstname
   msgbox objUser.lastname
   msgbox objUser.username
End Sub
```

Edit: To explain furter, I have this library script which is called 'libGetUserProperties'
It's in this I want the function and Class. Then I just import this library script in the actual script that is run at runtime. Looks like this:

libGetUserProperties:

```
Public Function getobjUser(ByRef Request, ByVal From)
    Dim thisUserObject
    Set thisUserObject = New objUser

    'If type = 0, data comes from AD
    If From = 0 Then
        thisUserObject.firstname = "some string"
        thisUserObject.lastname = "some string"  
    End If

    'If type = 1, data comes from Request stream
    If From = 1 Then
        thisUserObject.firstname = "some string"
        thisUserObject.lastname = "some string"    
    End If    

    Set getobjUser = thisUserObject

End Function

Class objUser
    Public firstname 
    Public lastname 
    Public username 
End Class'
```

This is what the actual runtime Script looks like:

```
Dim libGetUserProperties
Set libGetUserProperties = ScriptLib.Load("Script Modules/Library Scripts/libGetUserProperties")

Sub onPreCreate(Request)

    Dim userStream
    Set userStream = New objUser
    'Do whatever with objUser which contains all of the properties I'm after
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s not possible using VBScript, unless you want to dynamically generate the code for a class, including the properties, save that to file, and then execute that file as a script.

This is so much easier to do using JScript.  Since Windows Scripting can handle JScript as well as VBScript, I’d recommend going that way.

If you definitely need VBScript, the best you can go for is a Scripting.Dictionary that would contain the properties as keys:

```
Dim dicUser
dicUser = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dicUser("FirstName") = objUser.FirstName
```

which would allow you to access the first name as follows:

```
dicUser("FirstName")
```

---

**Update**

If you want to write a function which creates a dictionary and returns that, this is how to do it in VBScript:

```
Function RememberTheUser(Request)
    Dim dicResult
    Set dicResult = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dicResult("FirstName") = Request.GetTheFirstName
    Set RememberTheUser = dicResult
End Function
```

Which can then be assigned to some other variable:

```
Dim dicUser ' in the main section of the script, this means it's a global variable

Sub onPreCreate(Request)
  ' ...
  Set dicUser = RememberTheUser(Request)
  ' ...
End Sub


Sub onSomethingLater()
  WScript.Echo dicUser("FirstName") ' It's still accessible here
End Sub
```

---

In JScript, it’s a lot easier: just create a new object, and tack on new properties.

```
function readObject(dataSource) {
     var result = {};
     result.source = dataSource;
     result.firstName = dataSource.firstName;
     result['lastName'] = dataSource.FunctionThatGetsLastName();
}
```

Note that in JScript, object properties can be accessed using the `object.property` notation, but also through the `object['property']` notation, which is very useful when you have dynamically-named properties. (`'property'` in the second notation is a string, and can be replaced by any expression that returns a string).

Comment: Well, the thing is. I can't use Scripting.Dictionary because I'm getting this data before the user is even created. I do have the option of using JScript though. As well as PerlScript. VBscript is just what I've used to far.

Comment: What does Dictionary have to do with when the user is created?  Where are you getting the data from then?

Comment: I'm getting the data from a reference called Request. It's automated through event handlers that's called onPreCreate(Request). Where Request contains data on the object being created. Edit: Seems like I misunderstood Scripting.Dictionary as well

Comment: In that case, read `dicUser("FirstName") = Request.Whatever` should also work, wouldn’t it?

Comment: But is it possible to return the entire object to the initial Sub?At the first initial Sub I'd like to retrieve the properties of the user, through a separate Function that gets the properties and returns the object to the Sub. Then I can use that object throughout the rest of the script, in both Subs and Functions without having to retreive the properties more than once.

Comment: A function can return any variable or object you like, whether it be a JScript object, a Dictionary or a recordset -- I don’t quite see the problem.  If you want to make the object global to your script, you’ll have to assign it to a variable declared in the main section.  See updated answer

Comment: I see the updated answer :) I'm gonna try this out. I've also updated my first post, but it's nothing more than brainstorming really. Using a Class

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with VBScript, a disconnected recordset would work as well and is possibly faster than a dictionary; see [here](http://sogeeky.blogspot.com/2006/08/vbscript-using-disconnected-recordset.html) for an example.

Comment: I seriously doubt that a recordset would be faster than a dictionary.  Then again, I don’t have any evidence to back this up, nor the time to test it.